# System.OutOfMemoryException: Inputting images into expanderview

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, memorystream, bitmapimage, expander

I am attempting to take an image out of a database, convert it from bytes to bitmapimage and place it an expanderview within a list. This list contains as many expanderviews as there are entries in the database. This works perfectly until you exceed 6 entries. Then it displays the warning:

System.OutOfMemoryException:Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

This is my byte to bitmap converter:

```
public class ByteToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(byte[] imageByteArray)
    {
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
        {
            img.SetSource(memStream);
            memStream.Dispose();
        }
        return img;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        if (value != null)
        {
            img = this.ConvertByteArrayToBitMapImage(value as byte[]);
        }
        return img;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to call Dispose() explicitly if there is "using".

Comment: How big are these byte arrays?

Comment: Hard to give proper help with so small info, anyway you should implement a lazy-loading (and un-loading) logic for your images to avoid memory leak.

Comment: That disposed was part of my feeble debugging attempt and I forgot to get rid of it! You mentioned lazy-loading logic. This isn't something I've come across before. Is my attempt at conversion always going to cause memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

The BitmapImage object need to disposed when the use is completed.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slow reply. What would be the best method of disposing of the bitmapimage? There is a dispose method in the system.drawing namespace in .net, however, this is a windows phone application with no drawing namespace